# Is it safe to remove files from /var/crash

Tags: centos, disk-usage, crash

I'm receiving a disk usage warning from the server "
The filesystem “/” mounted at “/” reached “critical” status because you currently use 92.77% of its available blocks."

After deep investigation I found that /var/crash is using 56G. Is it safe to remove vmcore files from there without affecting server performance or boot?

Comment: sure (they're only useful for reporting problems).

Comment: And why is there a `-1`, is the question out of place?

Answer (score 12):

You can delete files in under /var/crash if you're willing to lose useful information needed to debug those crashes.

Your bigger issue is what is causing all of those crashes.

It is most likely this folder is filled by corekeeper and it deletes every 7 days which means all those dumps happened recently.